# How can I comment on an individual line on Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I can add a comment to a cell, but not to a line within a cell. This is necessary as I want my peers to review my work. These reviews are more effective if the comments are linked to individual lines of code.

NB, I mean a social comment, not a commented out line of code:
[image]

Comment: Same like in python with // or #.